# Why does append retrospectively link the values in two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm initializing a list and then updating values in it, however the variable I am using for initializing the rows is also getting updated *retrospectively* - so to speak.

I expected this code to output `[['first', ''], ['', 'last']]`. How can I change my code so it outputs that?

```
array_row = ['', '']
array = []
# array = [['', '']]
array.append(array_row)
# array = [['first','']]
# array_row = ['first', '']  <---- !!! Why does array_row also get updated???
array[0][0] = 'first'
# array = [['first',''], ['first','']]
# array_row = ['first', '']
array.append(array_row)
# array = [['first','last'], ['first','last']]
# array_row = ['first', 'last']   <---- !!! Why does array_row also get updated???
array[1][1] = 'last'
# [['first', 'last'], ['first', 'last']]
print(array)
```

Comment: It doesn't retrospectively do anything. It's the same list, you're adding two references to it into the outer list.

Comment: Python doesn't make copies the way you're expecting. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks for this but how do I then append my list with empty values? In the way that I am trying to achieve in my code? I am not trying to make a copy.

Comment: Well you should be! Because if you don't make a copy and just keep reusing the same list, you've seen what happens.